How can I chang the order that tables are saved in
I have a datamodel that looks something like the following.

Booking

Component

Copy
Line Item

Main Copy Used
Line Item Additional Copy

Sub Copy Used









In the original legacy system the Copy was another top level table with a one to many relationship with the Line Item. Even across multiple bookings. However, each booking treated the Copy as if it was the only booking with that Copy.
In the new legacy system, we added a reference to the booking as part of making it easier to use.
We are currently writing an Entity Framework Core/GraphQL/Angular replacement for the new system and I am running into the issue that Entity Framework Core is trying to save the Copy table after the Line Item table because alphabetically the line item comes before the copy.
We are also loading the Copy as part of the component rather than as part of the line items because it's easier to look up the copy in code than deal with the headache of the same copy possibly existing in multiple places.
The reason this is an issue, is that the database is maintaining the foreign keys, and throws an error when we try to save the data.
This is the code I'm using to declare the copy and line item relationships in the component.
 modelBuilder.Entity<Component>(entity =>
 {
     entity.HasKey(e => new { e.BookingID, e.ComponentID}).HasName("pk_ComponentKey");

     entity.ToTable("component");
     entity.HasMany(e => e.Copy).WithOne(e => e.Component).HasForeignKey(e => new { e.BookingID, e.ComponentID});
     entity.HasMany(e => e.Lineitems).WithOne(e => e.Component).HasForeignKey(e => new { e.BookingID, e.ComponentID});

     entity.Property(e => e.BookingID)
         .HasMaxLength(6)
         .IsUnicode(false)
         .HasColumnName("bookingid");
     entity.Property(e => e.ComponentID)
         .HasMaxLength(32)
         .IsUnicode(false)
         .HasColumnName("componentid");
}

The Save method. Note, this a problem for new items, not for existing items. Additionally, we don't use database generated keys, we have our own unique table as we 0 pad the ID's to make them alpha sort correctly. Booking = Ad, Component = PubSchedule, Copy = Material, and Line Item = Adinsert.
  public void Save()
  {
      using (var pc = new PrintContext())
      {
          Ad originalAd;


          if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Ad.Creator))
          {
              Ad.Creator = Settings.CurrentProfile.Id;
              Ad.Credate = DateTime.Now;
              pc.Ads.Add(Ad);
              originalAd = Ad;
          }
          else { originalAd = Load(Ad.Ad1); pc.Update(originalAd); }
          Ad.Salesman = Settings.CurrentProfile.Profile.Salesman;
          Ad.Modifier = Settings.CurrentProfile.Id;
          Ad.Moddate = DateTime.Now;
          foreach(Pubschedule p in Ad.pubschedules)
          {
              p.Startdate = p.adinserts.Min(e => e.Pubdate);
              p.Stopdate = p.adinserts.Max(e => e.Pubdate);
          }
          foreach(Material m in (from ps in Ad.pubschedules from m in ps.materials where m.Credate == DateTime.MinValue select m))
          {
              m.Creator = Settings.CurrentProfile.Id;
              m.Credate = DateTime.Now;
          }

          var firstdate = (from ps in Ad.pubschedules
                           from ai in ps.adinserts
                           where !ai.Cancelled
                           orderby ai.Pubdate ascending
                           select ai.Pubdate).ToList();
          if (firstdate.Count > 0)
          {
              Ad.Firstdate = firstdate.First();
          }
          else
          {
              Ad.Firstdate = null;
          }
          if (InvoiceQuery)
              Ad.Invoicequery = DateTime.Now;
          //if (materialDeleted)
          //{
          //    DAL.SaveDataSet(adDetails, lasttables: new List<string>(new[] { "material" }));
          //}
          //else
          //{
          pc.Entry(originalAd).CurrentValues.SetValues(Ad);
          pc.SaveChanges();
          MyOrderBI.UpdateDetail(this);
      }


The question is unclear and the EF configuration code alone isn't enough. EF will persist all pending changes when SaveChanges is called in the correct order. If the primary keys are database-generated, it will ensure they're used properly and update the application objects with their new PK values. How are the objects inserted? Entity Framework Core is trying to save the Copy table after the Line Item table because alphabetically the line item comes before the copy. no it doesn't.

Please post the actual entities and the code that inserts objects. There's no relation between Copy and LineItem in the configuration. Entity Framework Core/GraphQL how are you doing that? Using what library? Please post enough code so others can reproduce the issue or at least understand what the application is doing.

@PanagiotisKanavos The Booking is brought in via a DTO, so the interface to the outside world doesn't actually matter. All that matters is that I have my booking entity from somewhere and I want to save it.

That doesn't matter to the database. If you get FK constraint violations, it means the model is missing relations. Otherwise EF would ensure the objects are stored in the correct order. Post the table scripts, the entities and the code that causes the problem. How are Copy and LineItem related? What's the actual error?

I have already given you the data structure at the top of the post. With table names swapped out for descriptive values. In the code there isn't a direct link between line item and copy because I bring the copy back as a list in the components. The data model I'm using is simplified from the database because it's a complicated mess to think about if I don't. Suffice to say, I need to save the Copy table before the Line item table.

That's a diagram, not tables and FK relations. Suffice to say it doesn't. You can't affect the order rows are saved because it doesn't matter. Unless there's a bug in the application code. You mentioned the database is maintaining the foreign keys, and throws an error when we try to save the data. That means there are Foreign key constraints that get violated. That would only happen if the wrong values were used, or if there's no relation between the entities.

Instead of adding the actual code and tables, create a new database, new classes and code that reproduces the error. From what you describe you shouldn't have to create more than 3 tables and entities (Component, Copy, LineItem)

There no relationship in the code for simplicity, not because there's no relationship between them. If the copy is saved first (which is what the new legacy system does) then there's no errors, as the line item can then reference the copy that's already in the database. But as the Line item table begins with "A" and the copy table begins with "M" the default ordering of the generated sql means it tries to put the line item in first. This was a problem in ADO.net too, and we ended up having to manually generate SQL to save it.

EF isn't ADO.NET and doesn't need a specific order. I've used ADO.NET since 2004, and before that ADO Recordsets which worked the same. A DbContext isn't a DataSet and you don't even need those Update calls. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work and already knows which of the object it tracks have changed.

I think you should go through the EF Core Quickstart tutorial to see how things really work with EF Core, and even how many-to-many relations can be handled without explicit ordering. Or even a join type. In the Many-to-many relations example you don't even need a PostTag entity to create a relation between Posts and Tags.

Then check the Saving related data section - you don't need an order. The entire graph of object is saved at once, with EF determining the order of insertion for Blog and Posts
